# How to disable all the links and input buttons on a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hyperlink

I am working in django and have created a class which has a field `closed`. When the user sets this value for a particular object, then I want to disable all buttons and links on the `object_view` page.

I am using the following `jquery` snippet, but it is not working. Can anybody help me find the mistake

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").css('cursor','arrow').click(function(){
        return false;
    });
    $("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
</script>
```

**Update:** Not working means that all the links and input buttons are still working, i.e. being directed to the correct page. I have included this code snippet in my `<head>` section.

Comment: Define "not working".  Does it do anything?  Are there errors on your console?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/x9JCU/

Comment: make sure you have jquery included

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").css("cursor","arrow").click(false);
  // for jquery older than 1.4.3, use the below line
  // $("a").css("cursor","arrow").click(function(){
  //   return false;
  // });

  $(":input").prop("disabled",true);
  // for jquery older than 1.6, use the below line
  // $(":input").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
</script>
```

You need the `$(document).ready(...)` so that the code doesn't run until the elements exist on the page.

Comment: $(":input") is going to filter all input elements; buttons, text boxes, submit buttons, etc.; not just input buttons as in my answer above yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working for all the links and buttons. However I am using `uploadify` and that didn't get disabled and instead of one it is now showing two buttons, where one is disabled and the other is not.  Why is there not backward compatibility for jquery greater than 1.6 because I have seen this working on other sites. I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to

Comment: @SamStriano That works fine for me in this case because I just want to render the page as `closed`

Comment: The commented out code will work in all versions, its just that the uncommented code is more correct in the newer versions and sometimes can be faster or be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could turn off all links (that is anchor tags) with something like this:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This should work for buttons and other inputs

```
$(":input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the whole thing in:

```
$(function() {

});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

To limit the input to buttons:

```
$('input[type="button"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Otherwise you disable all input elements.